# creating link with query string array by yii2

Tags: php, yii2

In Yii2 I need to create a link to

http://my.site/controller/view?val[]=1&val[]=2&val[]=3

```
Html::a('link',['controller/view','val[]'=>1,'val[]'=>2,'val[]'=>3])
```

obviously it doesn't work. Is there any possible workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should pass your values as an array, for example:

```
Html::a('link',['controller/view','val'=> [1, 2, 3]]);
```